# Correct way of coding a 'Guess the Number' game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and programming in general and I've written some code for a Guess the Number game in Python. It allows the user 6 attempts at guessing a random number. It works, however I am not sure if this is the best way or most efficient way of writing it and would appreciate it of I could get get some constructive feedback on it.

Code:

```
    #Guess my Number - Exercise 3
#Limited to 5 guesses

import random 

attempts = 1
secret_number = random.randint(1,100)
isCorrect = False
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))

while secret_number != guess and attempts < 6:

    if guess < secret_number:
        print("Higher...")
    elif guess > secret_number:
        print("Lower...")
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    attempts += 1

if attempts == 6:
    print("\nSorry you reached the maximum number of tries")
    print("The secret number was ",secret_number) 

else:
    print("\nYou guessed it! The number was " ,secret_number)
    print("You guessed it in ", attempts,"attempts")

input("\n\n Press the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: It looks pretty good to me. You could simplify that `if` condition in the `while` loop by replacing the `elif ...` with `else`.

Comment: try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If this code works and you're looking for improvements, this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (I've flagged it to suggest migration)

Comment: There is a small bug in your code: if someone guesses correctly with the sixth attempt, you print out the wrong message. Use `if attempts == 6 and secret_number != guess:`. Alternatively, check for `if secret_number == guess:`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd refactor your code to use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. Using a `for` loop removes the need to manually implement a counter variable:

```
import random

attempts = 5
secret_number = random.randint(1, 100)

for attempt in range(attempts):
    guess = int(input('Take a guess: '))

    if guess < secret_number:
        print('Higher...')
    elif guess > secret_number:
        print('Lower...')
    else:
        print()
        print('You guessed it! The number was ', secret_number)
        print('You guessed it in', attempts, 'attempts')

        break

if guess != secret_number:
    print()
    print('Sorry you reached the maximum number of tries')
    print('The secret number was', secret_number)
```